# Borrowed value does not live long enough in testing methods

Tags: rust

I am quite new to Rust (trying to move from Golang). So I've written a piece of code in Go and decided to try to write it in Rust.

The actual code is below:

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

pub struct WorkManager {
    pub threshold: i32,
}

impl WorkManager {
    pub fn new(trs: i32) -> Self {
        Self { threshold: trs }
    }

    pub fn run_job<T: Send + Sync>(&self, input: &'static Vec<T>, f: fn(&T) -> T) -> Vec<T> {
        if input.len() > self.threshold as usize {
            let mut guards: Vec<JoinHandle<Vec<T>>> = vec!();
            for chunk in input.chunks(self.threshold as usize) {
                let chunk = chunk.to_owned();
                let g = thread::spawn(move || chunk.iter().map(|x| f(x)).collect());
                guards.push(g);
            };
            let mut result: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(input.len());
            for g in guards {
                result.extend(g.join().unwrap().into_iter());
            }
            result
        } else {
            return input.iter().map(|x| f(x)).collect::<Vec<T>>();
        }
    }
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    const TRS_TEST: i32 = 10;

    fn testing_function(a: &u32) -> u32 {
        return 3 * a;
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_single() {
        let wm: WorkManager = WorkManager::new(TRS_TEST);
        let values: Vec<u32> = rand::thread_rng()
            .sample_iter(&Uniform::from(0..20))
            .take(TRS_TEST as usize - 1)
            .collect();
        assert_eq!(
            wm.run_job(&values, testing_function),
            values
                .iter()
                .map(|x| testing_function(x))
                .collect::<Vec<u32>>()
        );
    }
}
```

So the problem is when I run cargo test:

```
error[E0597]: `values` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:50:24
   |
50 |             wm.run_job(&values, testing_function),
   |             -----------^^^^^^^-------------------
   |             |          |
   |             |          borrowed value does not live long enough
   |             argument requires that `values` is borrowed for `'static`
...
56 |     }
   |     - `values` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Firstly, I was not using 'static' in function declaration, but I led to the problem with
I've read a lot about lifecycle, but I seem to be missing somethings, any ideas, please?

Comment: I hope you're aware you're reinventing the wheel [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon) and doing it less well, are you?

Comment: Do you understand what the `'static` lifetime means, and why the compiler forces you to use it here? Do you understand why is this requirement not fulfilled?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, Yes, I am aware :) As for static - doesn't it mean that the lifetime is just the whole lifetime of a program? Guess it does. I believe it forces me to use it because of borrowing it inside the cycle in `run_job` function (and probably because of spawn function). I do not understand, actually, that's why I am asking this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you wanted the following line:

```rust
let chunk = chunk.to_owned();
```

To create `Vec<T>` from the `&[T]` type of `chunk`. But it did not work. What happened here is rather bizarre.

You wanted to hit [the following impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-ToOwned):

```rust
impl<T: Clone> ToOwned for [T]
```

Let's pretend we are the compiler. We look for a method named `to_owned()` for the type `&[T]`. How does this process work? You can read more about this in [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules), but here's what happens in this case:

1. Since we've passed `&[T]`, we first loopkup for a method that takes `&[T]`. There is such one - `<[T] as ToOwned>::to_owned()` takes `&[T]`, since [`ToOwned::to_owned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#tymethod.to_owned) takes `&self`, and `self` is `[T]`. Is this method implemented? Well, yes, if `T: Clone`. Does this hold? No - we don't have this bound. Move on.
2. Look for a method that takes `&&[T]`. Does it exist? Yes, `<&[T] as ToOwned>::to_owned()`. Is it implemented? [There is a blanket `impl<T: Clone> ToOwned for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#impl-ToOwned-5), so it is implemented if `&[T]: Clone` holds. Does it? Well, yes: [every shared reference is `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations-1), and every `Copy` is also `Clone` ([`Copy` has `Clone` as a supertrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)).

So we found `<&&[T] as ToOwned>::to_owned()`. What does this method returns? It returns `&[T]` (since `<T: Clone as ToOwned>::Owned == T`, and in our case, `T` is `&[T]`). In conclusion, instead of creating `Vec<T>`, we ended up creating `&[T]` - or just copying our references, not fixing the issue at all!

If we'd used [`to_vec()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec) instead, which is more explicit, the compiler's error would also be more helpful:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: Clone` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:31:35
    |
31  |                 let chunk = chunk.to_vec();
    |                                   ^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `T`
    |
note: required by a bound in `slice::<impl [T]>::to_vec`
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
27  |     pub fn run_job<T: Send + Sync + std::clone::Clone>(&self, input: &Vec<T>, f: fn(&T) -> T) -> Vec<T> {
    |                                   +++++++++++++++++++
```

Applying this suggestion doesn't end the story, though we advanced:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
   --> src/lib.rs:32:25
    |
27  |     pub fn run_job<T: Send + Sync + Clone>(&self, input: &Vec<T>, f: fn(&T) -> T) -> Vec<T> {
    |                    -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `T: 'static +`
...
32  |                 let g = thread::spawn(move || chunk.iter().map(|x| f(x)).collect());
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:32:39: 32:83]` will meet its required lifetime bounds...
    |
note: ...that is required by this bound

error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
   --> src/lib.rs:32:25
    |
27  |     pub fn run_job<T: Send + Sync + Clone>(&self, input: &Vec<T>, f: fn(&T) -> T) -> Vec<T> {
    |                    -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `T: 'static +`
...
32  |                 let g = thread::spawn(move || chunk.iter().map(|x| f(x)).collect());
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `Vec<T>` will meet its required lifetime bounds...
    |
note: ...that is required by this bound
```

This happens because `T` can contain a lifetime *indirectly*, e.g. it can be `&'something_non_static i32`. Adding the bound `T: 'static + ...` indeed fixes all errors, and it now works!

Is it the best we can do? Definitely no. We're copying our data, and we don't really need it - we just did that in order to satisfy the borrow checker!

Since we don't really need our data to be `'static` and we're just forced into it because we're using threads, our best bet is to use crossbeams' [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) ([they're also going to be part of std](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93203)):

```rust
pub fn run_job<T: Send + Sync>(&self, input: &[T], f: impl Fn(&T) -> T + Sync) -> Vec<T> {
    if input.len() > self.threshold as usize {
        crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
            let mut guards = vec![];
            for chunk in input.chunks(self.threshold as usize) {
                let g = scope.spawn(|_| chunk.iter().map(|x| f(x)).collect::<Vec<_>>());
                guards.push(g);
            }
            guards.into_iter().flat_map(|g| g.join().unwrap()).collect()
        })
        .unwrap()
    } else {
        input.iter().map(|x| f(x)).collect()
    }
}
```

Note I also fixed some unidiomatic parts: e.g. passing `&Vec` is an antipattern - pass a slice instead. Also less type annotations, more iterators, `impl Fn` instead of `fn`, etc..

Scoped threads allow us to share non-`'static` data at the cost of our threads be forced to finish before we return (it'll `join()` implicitly before the scope object is dropped). Since we do that anyway, this does not matter.

But we're just reinventing the wheel. There is a library that automagically splits the work into threads, and does that way more efficiently than our implementation, using advanced work-stealing techniques - [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon)! And using it is as simple as:

```rust
pub fn run_job<T: Send + Sync>(&self, input: &[T], f: impl Fn(&T) -> T + Send + Sync) -> Vec<T> {
    use rayon::prelude::*;
    input.par_iter().map(f).collect()
}
```

Yep, that's all it takes (note that it does not guarantee order, however)!

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your answer. One of the best I've got so far!
Both of your solutions are working (not considering rayon to be a solution, since I am not able to use it due to the task). Also thank you for the explanation on what's going on actually with `chunks` and `threads`!

Also yes, crossbeam seems to be the thing I was looking for with non-static -- `Scoped threads allow us to share non-'static data at the cost of our threads be forced to finish before we return`, great catch!

Answer (score 1):

So, in the function you're trying to call, the pointer / reference is marked with a lifetime of static. That means, that that pointer has to be alive for the *entire* program. So, I don't really know how to *completely* fix it here, because the .chunks method requires static lifetime :( Sorry

Comment: No problem, appreciate your effort!